# Select a random subset of data

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, training-data

I have a dateset given to me that was previously split in training and validation (test) data. I need to further split the training data into a separate training data and calibration set, I don't want to touch my current validation (test) set. I don't have access to the original dataset.

I would like to do this randomly, so that every time I can run my script, I get a different training and calibration test. I am aware of the .sample() function but my training dataset is of 44000 rows.

## Original Datasets

```
training = dataset.loc[dataset['split']== 'train']
print("Training Created")
#print(training.head())

validation = dataset.loc[dataset['split']== 'valid']
print("Validation Created")
#print(validation.head())
```

Where I would need something like this:

```
# proper training set
x_train = breast_cancer.values[:-100, :-1]
y_train = breast_cancer.values[:-100, -1]
# calibration set
x_cal = breast_cancer.values[-100:-1, :-1]
y_cal = breast_cancer.values[-100:-1, -1]
# (x_k+1, y_k+1)
x_test = breast_cancer.values[-1, :-1]
y_test = breast_cancer.values[-1, -1]
```

Unsure what to do with the second split

## Example of Dataset

```
Object  | Variable | Split
Cancer1     55     Train
Cancer5     45     Train
Cancer2     56     Valid
Cancer3     68     Valid
Cancer4     75     Valid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as you already have a column with `train` and `validation` sets assigned. The usual way is to use [`sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html). So to further split your training data into training and "calibration", just use it on the train set (note that you have to split into `X` and `y`):

```
# initial split into train/test
train = df.loc[df['Split']== 'train']
test = df.loc[df['Split']== 'valid']

# split the test set into features and target
x_test = test.loc[:,:-1]
y_test = test.loc[:,-1]

# same with the train set
X_train = train.loc[:,:-1]
y_train = train.loc[:,-1]

# split into train and validation sets
X_train, X_calib, y_train, y_calib = train_test_split(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Thanks @yatu, this seems like a logical approach, would it be possible to do this to my current test data as well? I know it's confusing because my data is already split and labeled. So as I don't have access to the original data the model was trained on it is a bit difficult.

Comment: So the way to go about this is to split the train data into train and validation. So you train and then get an accuracy metric using the validation set. Then you reserve the unseen `test` set for the very end, normally for comparisson purposes @bio

Comment: Makes sense @Biohacker :) ?

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, I updated the question with a sample dataframe of how my data more or less looks. In the code you posted, your splitting the what would be the validation set am I correct?

Comment: Okay updated again, see if this makes more sense to you @bio

Comment: thanks this makes so much sense. I'm brand new to all this ML stuff so i feel a bit confused with these basic things haha

Comment: No worries, glad it helped :) @bio

Answer (score 1):

**1. Seperate the test set from the whole dataset**

**2. Then using the remaining dataset, split it into train and calibrate.**

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# define the test set
X_test = breast_cancer.values[-1, :-1]
y_test = breast_cancer.values[-1, -1]

# Get the remaining dataset 
X = breast_cancer.values[:-1, :-1]
y = breast_cancer.values[:-1, -1]

# Split the remaining dataset into train and calibration sets.
X_train, X_calib, y_train, y_calib = train_test_split(X, y)
```